# Select acessando duas tabelas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Possuo uma tabela Produto, com os campos marker, model e type.

Uma segunda tabela referente a laptops tem seus campos referentes a preço, RAM, outros campos e o model, que é o mesmo da tabela Produto.

Como fazer uma select que me informe o marker de um produto acessando seu código model?

Comment: Oi @William, você deve utilizar o `Inner Join` para fazer a junção das tabelas, neste [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) tem algumas informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal isso?

```
SELECT p.marker
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN laptops lap ON p.model = lap.model
WHERE lap.model = ?
```

Onde `?` é o model do laptop.

No entanto, talvez você queira mostrar vários campos do produto e do laptop:

```
SELECT p.marker, p.type, p.model, lap.preco, lap.ram, lap.outrocampo
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN laptops lap ON p.model = lap.model
WHERE lap.model = ?
```

Entretanto, se por outro lado você quiser apenas o `model` e nada mais, então considerando que a consulta não traz nenhum campo da tabela `laptops` e que o código dado para o laptop é o mesmo da tabela `produto`, logo você poderia simplificar para ter isso:

```
SELECT p.marker
FROM produto p
WHERE p.model = ?
```

Comment: Obrigado Victor, as duas soluções funcionaram, eu acabei testando da seguinte forma :                                                                                    select laptop.model,speed,hd,marker
  from laptop inner join product
  on (laptop.model = product.model)

Comment: @William Se tudo deu certo, então peço que por favor sinalize a minha resposta como aceita (é o certinho verde em baixo dos números da votação).

Comment: @William Obrigado. :D